# How to find the power supplied by the ideal current source?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, current-measurement, current-source, homework

In this question I have already found the current in the three meshes given using mesh analysis, they are (i1 = top mesh , i2 = bottom left, i3 = bottom right).

How to find the power supplied by the ideal current source?

---

[image: question text and diagram]

Comment: As far as I know, Power = Voltage * Current. So if you know voltage and current, you can calculate power.

Comment: You haven't "found" the currents, so far you have just assigned variables to them.  You need to actually calculate them.

Comment: Chris, I think they meant that they had already found the value of the mesh currents in their previous efforts of solving this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's homework without an attempt at a solution, provide the solution and reopen the question

Answer (score 1):

\$P=VI\$

If you know the current that is supplied by the current source, all you need to do is find the voltage across the current source. You can do that by applying Kirchhoff's Voltage Law on any of the 2 bottom loops, using the mesh / loop currents you had already found. Pay attention to the currents' and voltages' polarity!
[image]

Good luck :)